# How to show double qoutes with a variable when writing to a file in c#?

Tags: c#, string, file-writing

I am trying to write a string to a file using C#, the output i am looking for should be like this

```
<meta name="geo.region" content="Asia"/>
```

to achieve this i have tried this code,

```
writer.WriteLine(@"<meta name=""geo.region"" content="""+MetaTags.Region+"""/>");
```

but the output is,

```
<meta name="geo.region" content="Asia/>
```

No double quotes after "Asia"

I have also tried

```
 writer.WriteLine(@"<meta name=""geo.region"" content="""+MetaTags.Region+"""/>");
```

but it shows a syntax error

Comment: Your code samples are the same currently

Comment: Use a proper XML serializer instead of emitting raw strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use two double-quotes to produce a double-quote in the result, the string literal needs to be prepended with `@`.  So this is a syntax error:

```
"""/>"
```

But this isn't:

```
@"""/>"
```

Simply add the `@` to your string literal as you already do for your other string literal:

```
writer.WriteLine(@"<meta name=""geo.region"" content=""" + MetaTags.Region + @"""/>");
```

Alternativly, if this is a recent enough version of C#, you can clean it up a little with string interpolation:

```
writer.WriteLine($"<meta name=\"geo.region\" content=\"{MetaTags.Region}\"/>");
```

If you prefer back-slashes to double-double-quotes that is.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use a backslash before a double quote instead of doubling it:

```
writer.WriteLine("<meta name=\"geo.region\" content=\"" + MetaTags.Region + "\"/>");
```

Using string interpolation:

```
writer.WriteLine($"<meta name=\"geo.region\" content=\"{MetaTags.Region}\"/>");
```

It will output:

```html
<meta name="geo.region" content="region"/>
```

More details:

[Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings)

[String interpolation in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)

Comment: Not that this question needed any new answers, given that it's an obvious duplicate. But I think you mean "backslash", not "backspace".